# Propel configuration file not found

Tags: php, mysql, orm, propel

when trying to reverse engineer a shema.xml in Propel i get the error message "Propel configuration file not found"

I created a new directory with a fairly standard build.properties file which i used before.
But for some reason it's now looking for a different config file.

Hope someone can help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am getting this too. Turns out they've broken/changed something in the most recent dev commit.

I am using composer and have fixed it by forcing a rollback to an older commit.

In my composer.json I have a require line of:

`"propel/propel": "dev-master#b412f08c98c83e05acd1e6e8357a177e7e26d047"`

Then do a 
`$ composer update`

And it should work again.

Comment: I have created a new issue with the developers. If this is not a bug then hopefully they will let us know what has changed so we can adapt our console parameters or our runtime-conf.xml

Comment: I had the same problem and can confirm the workaround works. Thanks!

Comment: I've heard from the Propel dev team. They are changing the way Propel2 is configured and the new documentation hasn't hit the main branch yet. You can find the work-in-progress documentation here: https://github.com/propelorm/Propel2/pull/527

Comment: Propel's Website has now information about the current configuration system.

Answer (score 2):

starting from commit 753bcc9 Propel has a new configuration system.

Now there's only one configuration file and you can choose your favorite fromat in: yaml, php, xml, ini and json.

You can find the full documentation in [this PR](https://github.com/propelorm/propelorm.github.com/pull/296). It's not merged by now: we're reviewing my awful English.

<s>There's [this issue](https://github.com/propelorm/Propel2/issues/668) by now: some configured paths are ignored because of a bug in command files ('build' command saves the generated files always in 'generated-class' subdir, ignoring your configuration). I'm working on it and I hope to fix it this weekend.</s>

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Leave here a dirty but working the [config.yaml](https://gist.github.com/Sorbing/96145d249b0c87a2c2a2) as example. I look forward to updating the documentation.